# Отчеты в Excel на Android

Tags: android

Какие библиотеки есть для андроид для создания отчетов в Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартной библиотекой для доступа к файлам Microsoft Office для Java является [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

Существуют порты POI под Android, достаточно [погуглить в Github](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=android+poi&type=Repositories)